# Forming this type of variables in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
var Var1 = ["0"];
var Var2 = ["0"];
var Var3 = ["0"];
var Var4 = ["0"];
```

How can i form this type of variables in java. This is of JavaScript. I tried something like this, but fail.

```
Array Var1[] = new["0"];
```

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the Java [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)?

Comment: Wait, you're asking **this** with 995 rep?!?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax differs for Java:

```
String[] var1 = { "0" };
```

You can also do this:

```
String[] var1 = new String[] { "0" };
```

although the second `String[]` is optional in the array declaration.

Also

```
int[] var1 = { 0 };
```

for integer types.

See: [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: String[] var1 = new String[] { "0" }; How come we are passing {} object literals here.

Comment: The braces delimit the array content assignment. Everything inside of them _is_ the contents of the array.